# Can't send HTTPS request through proxy using urlib2

Tags: python, https, openssl, urllib2

I'm trying to create a Python script that sends a HTTPS request through a proxy (Burp, to be exact), but it keeps failing with

```
ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'example.com:443' doesn't match u'example.com'
```

Here's an abbreviated version of my code:

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': '127.0.0.1:8080'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)

opener.addheaders = [ ("Host", "example.com"),
                    ...
                    ]
urllib2.install_opener(opener)  
try:
    req = opener.open( 'https://example.com/service', 'data' ).read()
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print e
```

So it looks like Python thinks that Python (`ssl.CertificateError` is, I believe, a Python error, not an OpenSSL error) has a problem with either the port or that one of the addresses is in Unicode. Neither makes sense to me. Any sugestions?

Comment: Please post the certificate that is being used by the server at `127.0.0.1:8080`. Also, 8443 is usually used as the alternate HTTPS port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code. i got it working with `burp`

**test.py**

```
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener(
                urllib2.HTTPHandler(),
                urllib2.HTTPSHandler(),
                urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': 'localhost:8080'}))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
print opener.open( 'https://example.com', 'data' ).read()
```

**burp configuration**

[image]

---

### Demo

[image]

Comment: Nope. Same result. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: The odd thing is that it is actually sent through Burp and receives a response, so the cert has already been dealt with. Why there would be an issue is beyond me.